# SpringBoot - observability on *_max *_count *_sum metrics

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, spring-boot-actuator

Small question regarding Spring Boot, some of the useful default metrics, and how to properly use them in Grafana please.

Currently with a Spring Boot 2.5.1+ (question applicable to 2.x.x.) with Actuator + Micrometer + Prometheus dependencies, there are lots of very handy default metrics that come out of the box.

I am seeing many many of them with pattern `_max _count _sum`.

Example, just to take a few:

```
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum

reactor_netty_http_client_data_received_bytes_max
reactor_netty_http_client_data_received_bytes_count
reactor_netty_http_client_data_received_bytes_sum

http_server_requests_seconds_max
http_server_requests_seconds_count
http_server_requests_seconds_sum
```

Unfortunately, I am not sure what to do with them, how to correctly use them, and feel like my ignorance makes me miss on some great application insights.

Searching on the web, I am seeing some using like this, to compute what seems to be an average with Grafana:

```
irate(http_server_requests_seconds::sum{exception="None", uri!~".*actuator.*"}[5m]) / irate(http_server_requests_seconds::count{exception="None", uri!~".*actuator.*"}[5m])
```

But Not sure if it is the correct way to use those.

May I ask what sort of queries are possible, usually used when dealing with metrics of type `_max _count _sum` please?

Thank you

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*UPD 2022/11:* Recently I've had a chance to work with these metrics myself and I made a dashboard with everything I say in this answer and more. It's available on [Github](https://github.com/anemyte/spring-http-dashboard) or [Grafana.com](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/17360-spring-http-example/). I hope this will be a good example of how you can use these metrics.

*Original answer*:

`count` and `sum` are generally used to calculate an average. `count` accumulates the number of times `sum` was increased, while `sum` holds the total value of *something*. Let's take `http_server_requests_seconds` for example:

```
http_server_requests_seconds_sum   10
http_server_requests_seconds_count 5
```

With the example above one can say that there were 5 HTTP requests and their combined duration was 10 seconds. If you divide `sum` by `count` you'll get the average request duration of 2 seconds.

Having these you can create at least two useful panels: average request duration (=average latency) and request rate.

##### Request rate

Using [rate()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) or [irate()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#irate) function you can get how many there were *requests per second*:

```
rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[5m])
```

`rate()` works in the following way:

1. Prometheus takes samples from the given interval (`[5m]` in this example) and calculates difference between current timepoint (not necessarily now) and `[5m]` ago.
2. The obtained value is then divided by the amount of seconds in the interval.

Short interval will make the graph look like a saw (every fluctuation will be noticeable); long interval will make the line more smooth and slow in displaying changes.

##### Average Request Duration

You can proceed with

```
http_server_requests_seconds_sum / http_server_requests_seconds_count
```

but it is highly likely that you will only see a straight line on the graph. This is because values of those metrics grow too big with time and a really drastic change must occur for this query to show any difference. Because of this nature, it will be better to calculate average on interval samples of the data. Using [increase()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) function you can get an *approximate* value of how the metric changed during the interval. Thus:

```
increase(http_server_requests_seconds_sum[5m]) / increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count[5m])
```

The value is approximate because under the hood `increase()` is `rate()` multiplied by `[inverval]`. The error is insignificant for fast-moving counters (such as the request rate), just be ready that there can be an increase of 2.5 requests.

##### Aggregation and filtering

If you already ran one of the queries above, you have noticed that there is not one line, but many. This is due to labels; each unique set of labels that the metric has is considered a separate time series. This can be fixed by using an [aggregation function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) (like `sum()`). For example, you can aggregate request rate by `instance`:

```
sum by(instance) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[5m]))
```

This will show you a line for each unique `instance` label. Now if you want to see only some and not all instances, you can do that with a filter. For example, to calculate a value just for `nodeA` instance:

```
sum by(instance) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{instance="nodeA"}[5m]))
```

Read more about selectors [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors). With labels you can create any number of useful panels. Perhaps you'd like to calculate the percentage of exceptions, or their rate of occurrence, or perhaps a request rate by `status` code, you name it.

##### Note on `max`

From what I found on the web, `max` shows the maximum recorded value during some interval set in settings (default is 2 minutes if to trust the source). This is somewhat uncommon metric and whether it is useful is up to you. Since it is a Gauge (unlike `sum` and `count` it can go both up and down) you don't need extra functions (such as `rate()`) to see dynamics. Thus

```
http_server_requests_seconds_max
```

... will show you the maximum request duration. You can augment this with aggregation functions (`avg()`, `sum()`, etc) and label filters to make it more useful.